# Remove white page that appeared out of nowhere

Tags: page, white-space

This is (part) my code:

```
\bibliography{biblio}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\onecolumn
\begin{appendices}

\section{\\Images}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        \subfloat[Car no noise]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/car_13.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Car (S\&P 2\%)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/car_13_2.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Car (S\&P 2\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/car_13_2d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Car (S\&P 5\%)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/car_13_5.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Car (S\&P 5\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/car_13_5d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Car (S\&P 7\%)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/car_13_7.jpeg}} \\
        \subfloat[Car (S\&P 7\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/car_13_7_deno.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Car (Gauss std=15)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/car_13_15.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Car (Gauss std=15) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/car_13_15d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Car (Gauss std=30)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{car_13_noise.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Car (Gauss std=30) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{car_13_de_noised.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Car (Gauss std=45)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/car_13_45.jpeg}} \\
        \subfloat[Car (Gauss std=45) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/car_13_45d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House no noise]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/house_902.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House (S\&P 2\%)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/house_902_2.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House (S\&P 2\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/house_902_2d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House (S\&P 5\%)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/house_902_5.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House (S\&P 5\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/house_902_5d.jpeg}} \\
        \subfloat[House (S\&P 7\%)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/house_902_7.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House (S\&P 7\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/house_902_7d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House (Gauss std=15)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/house_902_15.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House (Gauss std=15) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/house_902_15d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House (Gauss std=30)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{house_902_noise.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House (Gauss std=30) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{house_902_de_noised.jpeg}} \\
        \subfloat[House (Gauss std=45)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/house_902_45.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House (Gauss std=45) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/house_902_45d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House number no noise]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/number_1473.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House number (S\&P 2\%)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/number_1437_2}} &
        \subfloat[House number (S\&P 2\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/number_1473_2d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House number (S\&P 5\%)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/number_1473_5.jpeg}} \\
        \subfloat[House number (S\&P 5\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/number_1473_5d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House number (S\&P 7\%)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/number_1473_7.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House number (S\&P 7\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/number_1473_7d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House number (Gauss std=15)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/number_1473_15.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House number (Gauss std=15) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/number_1473_15d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House number(Gauss std=30)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{number_1473_noise.jpeg}} \\

    \end{tabular}
\caption{(scaled at 0.6)}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        \subfloat[House number(Gauss std=30) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{number_1473_de_noised.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House number (Gauss std=45)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/number_1473_45.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[House number (Gauss std=45) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/number_1473_45d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[River no noise]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/river_113.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[River (S\&P 2\%)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/river_113_2}} &
        \subfloat[River (S\&P 2\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/river_113_2d.jpeg}} \\
        \subfloat[River (S\&P 5\%)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/river_113_5.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[River (S\&P 5\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/river_113_5d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[River (S\&P 7\%)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/river_113_7.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[River (S\&P 7\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/river_113_7d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[River (Gauss std=15)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/river_113_15.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[River (Gauss std=15) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/river_113_15d.jpeg}} \\
        \subfloat[River (Gauss std=30)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{river_113_noise.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[River (Gauss std=30) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{river_113_de_noised.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[River (Gauss std=45)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/river_113_45.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[River (Gauss std=45) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/river_113_45d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Road no noise]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/road_555.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Road (S\&P 2\%)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/road_555_2}} \\
        \subfloat[Road (S\&P 2\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/road_555_2d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Road (S\&P 5\%)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/road_555_5.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Road (S\&P 5\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/road_555_5d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Road (S\&P 7\%)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/road_555_7.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Road (S\&P 7\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/road_555_7d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Road (Gauss std=15)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/road_555_15.jpeg}} \\
        \subfloat[Road (Gauss std=15) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/road_555_15d.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Road (Gauss std=30)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{road_555_noise.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Road (Gauss std=30) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{road_555_de_noised.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Road (Gauss std=45)]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/road_555_45.jpeg}} &
        \subfloat[Road (Gauss std=45) de-noised]{\includegraphics[scale = 0.6]{images/road_555_45d.jpeg}}\\
    \end{tabular}
\caption{(scaled at 0.6)}
\end{figure}

\section{\\Pseudo-code}

    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \algorithmicrequire image, noise\_percent\\
        \algorithmicensure nosy\_image\\
        \State $height$ = get image height\;
        \State $width$ = get image width\;
        \For{i=0 to width}
            \For{j=0 to height}\
                \State random = compute random number\;
                \If{$random < noise\_percent$}
                    \State $pixel = image[i][j]$\;
                    \If{pixel is dark}
                        \State $image[i][j]$ = white\;
                    \EndIf    
                    \If{pixel is bright}
                        \State $image[i][j]$ = black\;
                \EndIf  
    \caption{Salt\&Pepper noise}
    \end{algorithm}

    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \algorithmicrequire image, st\_dev, mean\\
        \algorithmicensure nosy\_image\\
        \State $perturbance$ = compute Gaussian perturbance with givet $st\_dev$ and $mean$\;
        \State $noisy\_image$ = $image$ + $perturbance$ \\
        \Return $noisy\_image$
    \caption{Gaussian noise}
    \end{algorithm}

\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

between the `References` and `Appendix` a white page is generated and I can't seem to get rid of it :/

Any help is greatly appreciated

---

**EDIT**

From what I could gather is that \onecolumn dictates where the white page is introduced. If I put it after `\begin{appendices}` the `Title` `Appendix`  will appear right after the references, followed by a white page and the rest of the `appendix`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Why are there double-backslash directives inside the arguments of the two `\section` directives?

Comment: @samcarter I'll try my best to create one but I see it kinda hard without giving you all my Thesis.

Comment: @Mico That is for style preference, teacher told me to do that (so it goes one line below)

Comment: What I could gather is that ``\onecolumn`` dictates where the white page is introduced.

Comment: The `[H]` placement directives for the `figure` and `algorithm` environments pretty much guarantee that if there's not enough space on the current page, the float will be moved immediately to the top of the next page, resulting in a huge unsightly block of whitespace on the current page. What happens if you simply omit the `[H]` directives?

Comment: @Mico by removind the ``[H]`` the 2 ``figures`` get placed after the ``algorithm`` and leave ``Images`` (title of appendix) empty of content

Comment: It sounds very much like the `figure` environments exceed the height of the textblock. Can you either reduce the (vertical) sizes of the`figure` environments or break up the material in the figures into smaller (and, naturally, more numerous) units?

Answer (score 1):

- number of subfloats per figure is to large for numbering them by letters. *possible solution*: number them by numbers for example as (1-32), where 1 is figure number and 32 subfloat number:

  ```
  \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure-\arabic{subfigure}}
  ```
- size of figure with 32 images probably exceed size of text block. *possible solution*: split first image to two parts and use `\ContinuedFloat`
   macro from the `caption` package
- instead of the `scale` option rather use `width` and set it to width of table's columns (i suggest to use the `tabularx` environments for table)
- for shorter code use keys `Gin` by which determine size of all images in both figures

considering above, the code for both figures is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\onecolumn

\begin{appendices}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \captionsetup[subfloat]{font=footnotesize,
                            labelformat=parens, labelsep=space,
                            justification=centering}
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, height=24mm}
    \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure-\arabic{subfigure}}

\section{Images}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{6}{X}}
\subfloat[Car no noise]{\includegraphics{images/car_13.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Car (S\&P 2\%)]{\includegraphics{images/car_13_2.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Car (S\&P 2\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/car_13_2d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Car (S\&P 5\%)]{\includegraphics{images/car_13_5.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Car (S\&P 5\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/car_13_5d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Car (S\&P 7\%)]{\includegraphics{images/car_13_7.jpeg}} \\

\subfloat[Car (S\&P 7\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/car_13_7_deno.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Car (Gauss std=15)]{\includegraphics{images/car_13_15.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Car (Gauss std=15) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/car_13_15d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Car (Gauss std=30)]{\includegraphics{car_13_noise.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Car (Gauss std=30) de-noised]{\includegraphics{car_13_de_noised.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Car (Gauss std=45)]{\includegraphics{images/car_13_45.jpeg}} \\

\subfloat[Car (Gauss std=45) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/car_13_45d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House no noise]{\includegraphics{images/house_902.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House (S\&P 2\%)]{\includegraphics{images/house_902_2.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House (S\&P 2\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/house_902_2d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House (S\&P 5\%)]{\includegraphics{images/house_902_5.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House (S\&P 5\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/house_902_5d.jpeg}} \\

\subfloat[House (S\&P 7\%)]{\includegraphics{images/house_902_7.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House (S\&P 7\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/house_902_7d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House (Gauss std=15)]{\includegraphics{images/house_902_15.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House (Gauss std=15) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/house_902_15d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House (Gauss std=30)]{\includegraphics{house_902_noise.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House (Gauss std=30) de-noised]{\includegraphics{house_902_de_noised.jpeg}} \\

\subfloat[House (Gauss std=45)]{\includegraphics{images/house_902_45.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House (Gauss std=45) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/house_902_45d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House number no noise]{\includegraphics{images/number_1473.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House number (S\&P 2\%)]{\includegraphics{images/number_1437_2}} &
\subfloat[House number (S\&P 2\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/number_1473_2d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House number (S\&P 5\%)]{\includegraphics{images/number_1473_5.jpeg}} \\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{(scaled at 0.6)}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{6}{X}}
\ContinuedFloat
\subfloat[House number (S\&P 5\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/number_1473_5d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House number (S\&P 7\%)]{\includegraphics{images/number_1473_7.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House number (S\&P 7\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/number_1473_7d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House number (Gauss std=15)]{\includegraphics{images/number_1473_15.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House number (Gauss std=15) de-noised] {\includegraphics{images/number_1473_15d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House number(Gauss std=30)]{\includegraphics{number_1473_noise.jpeg}}
\end{tabularx}
\caption{(scaled at 0.6)}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{6}{X}}
\subfloat[House number(Gauss std=30) de-noised]{\includegraphics{number_1473_de_noised.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House number (Gauss std=45)]{\includegraphics{images/number_1473_45.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[House number (Gauss std=45) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/number_1473_45d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[River no noise]{\includegraphics{images/river_113.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[River (S\&P 2\%)]{\includegraphics{images/river_113_2}} &
\subfloat[River (S\&P 2\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/river_113_2d.jpeg}} \\

\subfloat[River (S\&P 5\%)]{\includegraphics{images/river_113_5.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[River (S\&P 5\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/river_113_5d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[River (S\&P 7\%)]{\includegraphics{images/river_113_7.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[River (S\&P 7\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/river_113_7d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[River (Gauss std=15)]{\includegraphics{images/river_113_15.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[River (Gauss std=15) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/river_113_15d.jpeg}} \\

\subfloat[River (Gauss std=30)]{\includegraphics{river_113_noise.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[River (Gauss std=30) de-noised]{\includegraphics{river_113_de_noised.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[River (Gauss std=45)]{\includegraphics{images/river_113_45.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[River (Gauss std=45) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/river_113_45d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Road no noise]{\includegraphics{images/road_555.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Road (S\&P 2\%)]{\includegraphics{images/road_555_2}} \\

\subfloat[Road (S\&P 2\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/road_555_2d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Road (S\&P 5\%)]{\includegraphics{images/road_555_5.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Road (S\&P 5\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/road_555_5d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Road (S\&P 7\%)]{\includegraphics{images/road_555_7.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Road (S\&P 7\%) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/road_555_7d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Road (Gauss std=15)]{\includegraphics{images/road_555_15.jpeg}} \\

\subfloat[Road (Gauss std=15) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/road_555_15d.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Road (Gauss std=30)]{\includegraphics{road_555_noise.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Road (Gauss std=30) de-noised]{\includegraphics{road_555_de_noised.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Road (Gauss std=45)]{\includegraphics{images/road_555_45.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[Road (Gauss std=45) de-noised]{\includegraphics{images/road_555_45d.jpeg}}
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{(scaled at 0.6)}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

[image]